# What should I do if I get my adapter prong stuck in the outlet?

Tags: receptacle

So the metal thing that you plug into the outlet broke and got stuck inside the outlet and I don’t know if this dangerous, what should I do? I live in an apartment building so I don’t have one of those circuit breakers to shut off the outlets to take out the prong.

Comment: Which prong? A photo would be great. The longer ground prong tends to break first, and you can safely pull that one without switching off the breaker.

Comment: Eh, your apartment does not have a breaker panel in it anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to talk to the apartment complex supervisor and get them to send out the complex maintenance person or applicable contractor to correct this problem.

It the broken off prong is sticking out of the outlet and it is on the mains hot wire side it can be a dangerous thing if someone were to touch it. Make sure to warn others about the potential danger until this is serviced / replaced. If there are small children in the unit make sure that they have no access to that area as well.

Outlets are a relatively low cost item and in all likelihood the service person will replace the outlet with a new one.